# Jenkins-CLI command not executed from nodejs script

Tags: node.js, cmd, jenkins-cli

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://10.10.25.16:8088 -noKeyAuth offline-node NodeName
```

When the above jenkins-cli command is run from cmd , it is executing fine.
But when it is executed from a nodejs script as following, the expected behviour is not observed.

```
var properties = PropertiesReader('jenkins.properties');
var machineName = properties.get('machineName');
jenkinsCmd = "java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://10.10.25.16:8088 -noKeyAuth offline-node" + machineName ;
const child3 = exec(jenkinsCmd,
            (error, stdout, stderr) => {
              if (stderr)
                console.error(stderr);
            });
```

Any hint would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is the output of the console .error?

Comment: nothing is displayed in the console. I suppose the command is not getting executed at all.

Comment: have you declared jenkinsCmd variable before assign to it?

Comment: the same is getting executed when in parent process but not when in child process.

Comment: no i didn't declare

Comment: wrap your whole code into try catch block and see what exactly the problem is.

Comment: I was previously executing this in a child process with exec(). If it is in parent process then it was working fine. So I executed it with execSync() and the expected behavior was observed. Hence solved!